# mysql - queries running slow after flushing cache and etc

Tags: mysql

my co-worker just flushed logs, privilegies, hosts, status, tables and etc. Now some queries are running very slow, about 10 times slower.

A simple select is fine but when i need to join and work with 100k+ rows things got ugly.

Any way to work around this?

Comment: Could be that caches were flushed too?

Comment: Just execute all those queries. Once you've done so, the cache will be warmed up again, and your queries will be faster if you execute them again.

Comment: i down know... running the same query takes the same time every request